# Nokogiri XSLT can transform with invalid stylesheet

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt, nokogiri

If I try to transform sample xml (`target.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root />
```

with invalid XSL stylesheet (`invalid.xsl`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <new-root />
  </xsl:stylesheet>
</xsl:template>
```

using Nokogiri (1.6.8.1) ruby v2.1.9:

```
require 'nokogiri'

print Nokogiri::XSLT(File.open('invalid.xsl'))
  .transform(Nokogiri::XML(File.open('target.xml')))
```

it will finish successfully:

```
# ruby program.rb
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<new-root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
```

How to configure nokogiri to validate XSL and throw an error if it's invalid?

Comment: Try whether setting strict parsing http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/ParseOptions helps.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks, but XML strict options didn't help (same result): `Nokogiri::XML(File.open('target.xml')) { |config| config.strict }`. It seems that  `Nokogiri::XSLT` doesn't have a configuration block like `Nokogiri::XML` has. I found possible workaround: read `xsl` with `Nokogiri::XML` with strict config, convert it back to string and read with `Nokogiri:XSLT`, but I'm not sure that it's the best option.

Comment: Hopefully someone with good knowledge of that API can help you further and tell you whether there is not a way to provide the options for the XSLT parsing or at least allow you to parse the stylesheet once with the `Nokogiri::XML` and the strict option to then pass that document on to the XSLT API without the need to serialize it back to a string.